# How to reference an array address of a VBA Max or Ubound function?

Tags: arrays, macos, excel, vba

How do I reference an array address where the WorksheetFunction.Max has found the largest value within the array? There can be multiple highs within the array.

```
Dim myArraySum(1 to 4) as long 
Dim myArrayAddress(1 to 4) as integer

myArraySum(1) = 2
myArraySum(2) = 5
myArraySum(3) = 7
myArraySum(4) = 7

           myArrayHigh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArraySum)
           myArrayAddress = 'code needed
```

My desired output is

```
myArrayHigh = 7
myArrayAddress(1) = 3
myArrayAddress(2) = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use a loop to check the values of every array element.

```
Function GetMaxIndicesArray(ByRef myArraySum() As Long, ByRef myArrayAddress() As Integer) As Integer
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, iLow As Integer, iUp As Integer
  Dim lMax As Long

  iLow = LBound(myArraySum)
  iUp = UBound(myArraySum)

  lMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArraySum)
  j = 1

  For i = iLow To iUp
    If (myArraySum(i) = lMax) Then
      myArrayAddress(j) = i
      j = j + 1
    End If
  Next

  GetMaxIndicesArray = j - 1
End Function

Sub test()
  Dim myArraySum(1 To 4) As Long
  Dim myArrayAddress(1 To 4) As Integer

  Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

  myArraySum(1) = 2
  myArraySum(2) = 5
  myArraySum(3) = 7
  myArraySum(4) = 7

  myArrayHigh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArraySum)
  'myArrayAddress = "" 'code needed

  n = GetMaxIndicesArray(myArraySum, myArrayAddress)

  Debug.Print "myArrayHigh = " & myArrayHigh
  For i = 1 To n
    Debug.Print "myArrayAddress(" & i & ") = " & myArrayAddress(i)
  Next

End Sub
```

Then in you debugger window, just type

```
test
```

The Result is like:

```
myArrayHigh = 7
myArrayAddress(1) = 3
myArrayAddress(2) = 4
```

Comment: Thank you for that code workup. So, in essence there is no built-in method or property I can refer to using the Worksheetfunction.Max or similar?

Comment: Not in my knowlodge... even after some googling.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple loop:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim myArraySum(1 To 4) As Long
   Dim myArrayAddress(1 To 4) As Integer
   Dim myArrayHigh As Long, k As Long, msg As String

   myArraySum(1) = 2
   myArraySum(2) = 5
   myArraySum(3) = 7
   myArraySum(4) = 7

   myArrayHigh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArraySum)

   k = 1
   For i = LBound(myArraySum) To UBound(myArraySum)
      If myArraySum(i) = myArrayHigh Then
         myArrayAddress(k) = i
         k = k + 1
      End If
   Next i

   msg = ""
   For i = LBound(myArrayAddress) To UBound(myArrayAddress)
      msg = msg & vbCrLf & i & vbTab & myArrayAddress(i)
   Next i

   MsgBox msg
End Sub
```